# Buscar aniversariantes do mês varchar

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal um cliente tem um campo **`datnasc`** do tipo **`varchar`** no banco de dados dele e agora ele quer buscar os aniversariantes do mês.

Como posso fazer isso sendo que os valores inseridos neste campo são neste padrão:

`dd/mm/aaaa = 16/03/2017`

Comment: Você quer fazer um select?

Comment: @Marconi sim quero fazer um select mostrando todos os registros que na datnasc tenha o mes /03/

Comment: Existe a opção para você fazer uma alteração na estrutura do Banco de Dados do seu cliente? Ou isso poderia trazer algum impacto para alguma aplicação que o está usando?
Bem, se você pode alterar a estrutura sem problemas, então use o link que o @VirgilioNovic comentou, caso contrario, a resposta dele também já resolveria, não esqueça de aceita-la como solução.

Comment: O seu campo é registrado desta forma: `dd/mm/aaaa = 16/03/2017` com todas as letras e números?

Answer (score 3):

Tem que transformar em data ([str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)) e depois conferir pelo mês ([MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)) que pega somente o mês de uma determinada data, apesar que o correto era gravar esse dado no formato `date` ou `datetime` no banco, ***exemplo***:

```
select * from tabela where MONTH(str_to_date(data, '%d/%m/%Y'))=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [Convertendo varchar em date no MySQL](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Convertendo-varchar-em-date-no-MySQL)
- [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [13.7 Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [function_month](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: @Miguel sim verdade, ta feita a alteração, obrigado...

Comment: De nada, vou apagar o comentário. Boa resposta

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função SUBSTR para pegar somente o mês de aniversário dos usuários. Veja:

```
<?php
    $mes = "03"; // mês atual ou escolhido para exibir os aniversariantes

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE SUBSTR('DATA_NASC', 3, 2) =".$mes;
    $qry = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $qry->execute();
?>
```

Nesse caso, dado uma data 16/03/2017(por exemplo) a função SUBSTR vai pegar os caracteres a partir da terceira posição com tamanho 2, ou seja, posição 3 e 4 onde fica o mês.